# Fex- Datagrid- custom header

Tags: apache-flex

I want to put a textinput box on the header of a datagrid in flex, whose values changes dynamically according to the no of data or value present in that perticular column.
Please any one help me, am posting the image acctually what I want. 
Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you can use Spark DataGrid. In that case you just need to create a custom headerRenderer. To keep things simple we'll start from the default headerRenderer. In your Flex SDK sources, find the class `spark.skins.spark.DefaultGridHeaderRenderer`. Copy this file into your project and rename it appropriately.

Inside this class, find the components `labelDisplayGroup` and `sortIndicatorGroup` (they're at the bottom). They're inside an HGroup, so we can simply add our counter component in between.

```
<!-- I removed the original comments for brevity -->
<s:HGroup left="7" right="7" top="5" bottom="5" gap="2" verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:Group id="labelDisplayGroup" width="100%" />
    <!-- our counter component -->
    <s:Label id="numRowsDisplay" />
    <s:Group id="sortIndicatorGroup" includeInLayout="false" />
</s:HGroup>
```

So far for the visual component; now we have to update its `text` property appropriately. In the script block add the following snippet:

```
private var dp:IList;

override public function set owner(value:DisplayObjectContainer):void {
    if (dp) dp.removeEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, updateNumRows);
    if (super.owner) super.owner.removeEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, onPropertyChange);

    super.owner = value;
    dp = value ? DataGrid(value).dataProvider : null;
    updateNumRows();

    if (dp) dp.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, updateNumRows);
    if (value) value.addEventListener(PropertyChangeEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, onPropertyChange);
}

private function onPropertyChange(event:PropertyChangeEvent):void {
    if (event.property == 'dataProvider') {
        dp = event.newValue as IList;
        updateNumRows();
    }
}

private function updateNumRows(event:CollectionEvent=null):void {
    numRowsDisplay.text = (dp ? dp.length : 0) + "";
}
```

What happens here? the `owner` property of the renderer refers to the data component that holds this renderer; in this case a DataGrid. So when the owner is assigned to the renderer, we access its `dataProvider` and use its `length` to update the counter component.

So what are those listeners for? There are two cases you might want to foresee.

- The number of items in the dataprovider changes: that's why we listen on the dataprovider for CollectionChange events.
- The entire dataProvider is changed or nullified: for this we listen for PropertyChangeEvents on the DataGrid and update the counter only when the 'dataProvider' property changes

Comment: I am working on flex builder3 is this answer applicable for flex builder 3.

Comment: Yes, but you have to use the Flex 4.5 SDK which doesn't come with Flex Builder 3: you'll have to add it manually.